# I need help to replace wordpress object with new one

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I want to replace slider image with [real slider](http://glpt.2gdmedia.com).

I mean I want to be new slider on same place, when I try TOP 5 Games are dissapearing or cant at all.

```
<?php if( function_exists('cyclone_slider') ) cyclone_slider('24'); ?>
```

By the way see original code:

```
<?php if(get_option('sam_728_disable') == "Yes") { ?>   
<?php } else { ?>
    <?php if( get_option("sam_728_90", true) ): ?>
        <div id="contop">
            <div class="contopleft">
                <?php echo stripslashes(get_option('sam_728_90')); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="contopright">
                <h2><?php _e("Top 5 Games", "Durus"); ?></h2>
                <?php if (function_exists('get_most_viewed')): ?>
                    <ol>
                        <?php get_most_viewed('post', 5); ?>
                    </ol>
                <?php endif; ?> 
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <div id="contop">
            <div class="contopleft">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/slidertest.png" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="contopright">
                <h2><?php _e("Top 5 Games", "Durus"); ?></h2>
                <?php if (function_exists('get_most_viewed')): ?>
                    <ol>
                        <?php get_most_viewed('post', 5); ?>
                    </ol>
                <?php endif; ?> 
            </div>  
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

All my attempt failed, so please anyone help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
<div id="contop">
            <div class="contopleft">
                <?php 
    echo do_shortcode("[metaslider id=65]"); 
?>
            </div>
            <div class="contopright">
                <h2><?php _e("Top 5 Games", "Durus"); ?></h2>
                <?php if (function_exists('get_most_viewed')): ?>
                    <ol>
                        <?php get_most_viewed('post', 5); ?>
                    </ol>
            <img src="adv.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <div id="contop">
            <div class="contopleft">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/slidertest.png" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="contopright">
                <h2><?php _e("Top 5 Games", "Durus"); ?></h2>
                <?php if (function_exists('get_most_viewed')): ?>
                    <ol>
                        <?php get_most_viewed('post', 5); ?>
                    </ol>
                <?php endif; ?> 
            </div>  
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```